# Summing timestamp returning incorrect value and format

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, type-conversion, aggregate-functions

I am looking to pull scheduled hours in a given time period. Our start and end schedule times are datetimes so I converted them to timestamps. When I dont sum them everything looks correct, but when I sum them over a time period, the output isnt in a timestamp format and the numbers are incorrect.

The query I am using:

```
select sal.public_name, sum(timediff(timestamp(end_time), timestamp(start_time)))
from bi.support_agents_list sal
join bi.support_sp_shifts_scheduled ss
on ss.agent_sp_id = sal.sp_id
join bi.support_sp_shifts s 
on s.pk_id = ss.pk_id
where date(start_time) between '2014-01-29' and '2014-01-31'
group by sal.public_name
```

A few examples of results I am getting:

Agent 1: 53000 - when it should be 5.5 hours or 5:30

agent 2: 196000 - when it should be 20 hours

Any thoughts on this? I would prefer my output to be in an hour count so 5 hours and 30 min is formatted as 5.5 rather than 5:30.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of the sum

```
   date_format(timediff(timestamp(end_time), timestamp(start_time)), 
   '%k hours, %i minutes, %s seconds') as thesum
```

like that

```
 select sal.public_name, 
   date_format(timediff(timestamp(end_time), timestamp(start_time)), '%k hours, %i minutes, %s seconds') as thesum
 from bi.support_agents_list sal
```

Comment: Thanks. When I do that, it works for a single timediff, but when I sum them, it rounds the output. so for agent 1 it gives me 5 rather than 5.5 or 5:30

Comment: how you sum them , give your example .

Answer (score 0):

When doing aggregate calculations with datetime sum(datetime), the result is not what you expect (=cannot sum datetimes). You will be better off converting the datetime to seconds before the aggregate function and then convert it back to time.

Your aggregate function call would then look something like:

```
select sec_to_time(sum(unix_timestamp(end_time)-unix_timestamp(start_time)))
```

Be aware that you may reach maximum value that time datatype can contain and that unix_timestamp starts from 1970.